# what's the difference between TELEPHONY_SERVICE1 and TELEPHONY_SERVICE

Tags: android, telephonymanager

In android system service ,there are TELEPHONY_SERVICE1 ="phone1" and TELEPHONY_SERVICE="phone" in android framework.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a source, but, I really believe it is used to retrieve TelephonyManager in Dual-Sim phones for the other card.

Except it being kinda obvious from the name, google also drops a lot of chinese results - coincidentally, Dual Sim phones are very popular in china.

I hope someone can back it up with a credible source or test it on a Dual Sim phone.